# rails has one through get selected value undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i would like to get the selected value from a has one through association
the associations are item and categories
with

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :categoryship
  has_one :category, through: :categoryship, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category

end
```

on item edit

```
<%= f.select :category_id, 
    options_for_select(
        Category.all.map{|rel| [rel.name, rel.id]},
        @item.category_id )
      %>
```

still not worked, ive tried on item edit and get the categoryship with category id, but still not get the selected category. someone can spare a hint on this?

```
  def edit

    @categoryship = @item.categoryship
    @category = @categoryship.where(category_id: category_id)
 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in your view you have `@item.category_id` but based on your model that fkey would be in `categoryships`, not in `items`.

Then in your controller code you seem closer, first you grab `@categoryship = @item.categoryship` which is good, because now in your view you can use `@categoryship.category_id`!

But then `@category = @categoryship.where(category_id: category_id)` is lost. I'm assuming in `Categoryship` you have a `belongs_to :category` so here in your controller you should just have `@category = @categoryship.category`.

Hopefully either that helps, or you can see how you really need to add more code here so we can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank your for your Answer! yes i get lost on 
which model point to!

Comment: but i still confuse why with @category = @categoryship.category still loging undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This is the first time you've said that's happening, you really need to edit your question to make it clear what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick a test framework and use it.
2. Learn to love the debugger.

Finally:  either of the following should just work:

```
  def edit
    @categoryship = @item.categoryship
    @category = @categoryship.category
    # OR
    @category = @item.category
  end
```

If they don't then something is wrong in your relationships or your database.  Hard to tell which without more information.

What you want to do is set a breakpoint (debugger) somewhere in the edit method and poke around the database.

Is @item nil?  There's your problem.
Is @item.categoryship nil?  If so, there's your problem.  Is it nil because it's missing in the database or because it's wired up wrong?
etc...

Comment: thank you, i already cheked if the db is wired ok before place the question, but ill check again with debugger!